# What is the correct procedure for adding SQL Server JDBC to GlassFish 3.1.2

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish-3

I am setting up a test GlassFish Server to learn NetBeans, Java, GlassFish web application development. I was able to do a basic deployment successfully and am moving on to databases.

I am trying to set up a MS SQL Server connection pool in the GlassFish admin. After configuring the datasource as javax.sql.Datasource and setting the properties, it fails to successfully ping the connection.

When I try to ping the connection, I get this error

```
Ping Connection Pool failed for SQLDB. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for :
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource
```

It looks like the .jar file isn't being loaded. I have placed the sqljdbc4.jar in the glassfish\modules folder.

What is the correct process for setting up a JDBC connection pool for SQL Server?

Comment: Can you show us what the current classpath looks like?

Comment: In the GlassFish JVM settings it says the CLASSPATH environment variable is not supported in v3

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using JRE 7 : use JDBC41 
in case you are using JRE 8 : use JDBC42 
Unzip the exe from the following link : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54671

Paste the jar in the lib folder of glassfish .

Once done define property under connection pool as URL and pass full qualified connection name as : jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\MSSQLSERVER:1433;databasename=AdventureWorks2016;integratedSecurity=true